# Mongodb text search for large collection

Tags: mongodb

Given below collection which has potential for ~18 million documents. I need a search functionality on the **payload** part of the document.
Because of the large volume of data, will it create performance issues if I create a text index on the payload field in the document? Are there any known performance issues when the collection contains millions of documents?

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5575e388e4b001976b5e570d"),
    "createdDate" : ISODate("2015-06-07T05:00:34.040Z"),
    "env" : "prod",
    "messageId" : "my-message-id-1",
    "payload" : "message payload typically 500-1000 bytes of string data"
}
```

I use MongoDB 3.0.3

Answer (score 0):

I believe that is exactly what NoSQL DB were designed to do; give you quick access to a piece of data via an [inverted] index. Mongo is designed for that. NoSQL DB's like Mongo are designed to handle massive sets of data distributed across multiple nodes in a cluster.  18 million in the scope of Mongo is pretty small.  You should not have any performance problems if you index property.  You might want to read up on `sharing` also, it is key to getting the best performance out of your MongoDB.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Mongo DB Atlas feature where you can search your text based on different Analyzers that MongoDB provides. And you can then do a fuzzy search where text closer to your text will also be returned:
PS: For full-text match and to ignore fuzzy, just exclude the fuzzy object from below.

```
$search:{
 {
  index: 'analyzer_name_created_from_atlas_search',
  text: {
    query: 'message payload typically 500-1000 bytes of string data',
    path: 'payload',
    fuzzy:{
      maxEdits: 2
    }
  }
 }
}
```